# Safe to power up the digital circuit for troubleshooting IC chips?

Tags: digital-logic, troubleshooting

I have a complex digital circuit board used in Scanning Electron Machine. 
In it, there are lot of IC chips, FPGA chips. diode SMD, capacitor SMD and others.
This problematic board produces no image. I am done with all discrete components except IC chips and FPGA. The question is, "Is it safe to power up each IC or other ICs nearby that share supply voltage and ground so that I can test them  with oscilloscope"?

Kindly advise me and thanks in advance.

Clement Yap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As happens most of the time the answer is maybe.

If you power up some ICs but not others then input lines that are supposed to have a defined input may be floating and output lines that go to other parts may be connected to an unpowered IC. When you power the input pins of an IC but not the power pins then the device will pull more current than expected from the inputs and due to the protection diodes on the pins will try to power itself from the input lines. This is something you should avoid if possible.

If these are 3.3V or lower parts then the chances are things won't get damaged however it does mean that things won't be in their normal state so just how valid your troubleshooting is is questionable.

Normally you want to power the whole board up to avoid this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to power up each IC or other ICs nearby that share supply
>   voltage and ground so that I can test them with oscilloscope?

An o-scope shows pictures of signal waveforms and if a target PCB isn't powered up then the only use an o-scope has is to look at input waveforms and this does not get you very far.

So power the whole digital circuit board and use the o-scope but try not to be clumsy and if some nodes look difficult to get the scope probes on then power down and solder a little wire that can be used as a probe hook.

Trying to half power one part of the circuit from another is step that is much more difficult so try and diagnose problems with the whole board powered up normally. Start with measuring chip voltages to ensure that the board is getting the full range of supplies it uses. In other words, start with basic measurements of DC voltages and currents (if possible) then move on to probing with the scope.